# OpenOfficeXml Repeat Labels in Pivot Table

Tags: c#, openxml, epplus, epplus-4

I m using Epplus and trying to "repeat all item labels" in tabular type pivot table.
I tried lots of things but it looks no way with EPPlus library. I decided to manulplate pivot table xml and i need to add **fillDownLabels** attribute on pivotTableFields but i m not sure how to do this.

```
private void ManuplateXml(OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.ExcelPivotTable pivotTable)
{

    var xdPivotTable = pivotTable.PivotTableXml;
    var xdPivotFields = xdPivotTable.FirstChild["pivotFields"];
    if (xdPivotFields == null)
        return;

    foreach (XmlElement pField in xdPivotFields)
    {
        pField.SetAttribute("fillDownLabels", "1");
    }
}
```

I write this method it added the attribute but my pivot table still doesnt repeat item labels. 
How should xml format be ? How can i use fillDownLabels attribute ?

Answer (score 4):

Construction `pField.SetAttribute("fillDownLabels", "true");` doesn't work.
Attribute `fillDownLabels` should be used on extension (`<ext>`) belonging to ExtensionList Class (`<extLst>`). Below my solution:

```
    private void ManipulateXml(OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.ExcelPivotTable pivotTable)
    {
        var pivotTableXml = pivotTable.PivotTableXml;
        var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(pivotTableXml.NameTable);
        nsManager.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main");
        nsManager.AddNamespace("x14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main");
        var topNode = pivotTableXml.DocumentElement;
        var nodes = topNode.SelectNodes("d:pivotFields/d:pivotField[@axis=\"axisRow\"]", nsManager);

        if (nodes == null) return;

        topNode.SetAttribute("updatedVersion", "6");//this line is important!
        foreach (XmlElement node in nodes)
        {
            var element = pivotTableXml.CreateElement("extLst", nsManager.LookupNamespace("d"));
            var ext = pivotTableXml.CreateElement("ext", nsManager.LookupNamespace("d"));
            ext.SetAttribute("uri", "{2946ED86-A175-432a-8AC1-64E0C546D7DE}");
            ext.SetAttribute("xmlns:x14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main");
            var fdLabels = pivotTableXml.CreateElement("x14:pivotField", nsManager.LookupNamespace("x14"));
            fdLabels.SetAttribute("fillDownLabels", "1");
            ext.AppendChild(fdLabels);
            element.AppendChild(ext);
            node.AppendChild(element);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `fillDownLabels` to `true`.  This is per the [OpenXML specification for the PivotField element which the fillDownLabels is an attribute of](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.office2010.excel.pivotfield.aspx).

To set it to true, use the following convention:

```
pField.SetAttribute("fillDownLabels", "true");
```

Also note from the spec that this attribute can be ignored in some situations:

> This attribute is ignored when the compact attribute and the outline attribute of the PivotTable ([ISO/IEC-29500-1] section 18.10) field (1) are "true". This attribute is ignored if the PivotTable ([ISO/IEC-29500-1] section 18.10) field (1) is not on the PivotTable ([ISO/IEC-29500-1] section 18.10) row (2) axis or the PivotTable ([ISO/IEC-29500-1] section 18.10) column (2) axis.

To summarize - to get your `fillDownLabels` to work correctly:

1. set the `fillDownLabels` to `true` - the default is `false`
2. make sure the `compact` attribute of the `outline` attribute of this pField is set or false (likely the default - check the spec).  If this is `true`, the fillDownLabels attribute is **ignored**.
3. Ensure the Pfield is on the row axis or column axis, otherwise `fillDownLabels` is **ignored**.

one last note for folks using OpenXMLSDK - to set a BooleanValue attribute you can use the convention:

`fillDownLabels = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true)`